# How to setup a domain name for my website hosted on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, webserver, hosting-services

I have created a django website and instead purchasing a hosting service, i have hosted the website on my own PC having public IP. Hence now i can access my website through my IP address.

Next step is to assign a domain name to my IP and hence everyone on internet can access my website through the domain name instead of IP. I know, there is a lot of sites for purchase a domain name but i don't want to purchase.

Is it possible to run a dns server on my system or anyother system connected to internet and set up a domain name for my website so that it can be accessed on internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** , it is not possible.

As domain entry has to present in [tld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) authoritative dns servers , which only registrar authorised by [ICANN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN) can insert via [EPP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Provisioning_Protocol) or some other way which tld provides like API, phone call, email, etc..

**Explanation** :
Whenever client will enter domain in his/her browser , it will do a DNS query , query will reach the root server and then tld server, but because tld server doesn't have any entry , client will not be able to get IP address and hence won't be able to reach you web server.

If you are thinking why anyone has to pay for the domian registration, there is a good explanation on this [stackexchange answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61467/if-icann-only-charges-18%C2%A2-per-domain-name-why-am-i-paying-10) .

**Terms :**

EPP protocol : a different protocol from DNS , to deal with name registration and provisioning

ICANN : a nonprofit organization responsible for coordinating the maintenance and procedures of several databases related to the namespaces of the Internet, ensuring the network's stable and secure operation